# ODBC escape convert error

Tags: excel, postgresql, odbc

I have configured connection to pgsql in excel (using ODBC driver).
When i execute sql query then i get an error "ODBC escape convert error"
Below is query (pseudocode)

`SELECT
    data1,
    data2
FROM
    (table) A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        schema.procedure (
            '{1706}',
            '2014-09-30 00:00:00',
            '2014-10-02 00:00:00',
            '{1,2}'
        )
) b ON A .some1 = b.some1
AND A .some2 = b.some2`

When i run first and second part of query (from excel connection) separately then everything is ok.
Some solutions suggest that i need to replace { with ( but it does not work.

I am waiting for support:)
I can give more informations if you need.

Best regards.

Comment: When you're asking about a specific error, please show (A) the **exact, unedited error**, (b) relevant versions like psqlODBC and PostgreSQL, and (c) **exact, unedited code**

Comment: I guess it is the strings inside {} as ODBC using {} to escape things like timestamp and date/times. However, IF removing the {} from those strings makes the error go away I'd suggest this driver is broken.

Comment: One thing is badgering me. Why this procedure (schema.procedura) is working when i executing it separately, even if it has '{'?

Comment: The {} are within string literals, so they won't be parsed as escape sequence characters. Unless the database is severely broken, it's something else.